# Is it possible to create a table with refs to rows in a other table in oracle sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, reference

I am implementing a small database in oracle sql to store infos about song and artists

```
create type song_t as object
(
    SONGID INTEGER,
    TITLE varchar2(100),
    GENRE varchar2(100),
    DATE_OF_CREATION date,
    BPM NUMBER 
);

create type artist_t as object
(
    ARTISTID INTEGER,
    NAME varchar2(100),
    SURNAME varchar2(100),
    DATE_OF_BIRTH date
);

create table SONG(
    SONGID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY not null,
    TITLE varchar2(100),
    GENRE varchar2(100),
    DATE_OF_CREATION date DEFAULT sysdate,
    BPM NUMBER 
);
/
create table ARTIST(
    ARTISTID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY not null,
    NAME varchar2(100) not null,
    SURNAME varchar2(100) not null,
    DATE_OF_BIRTH date
);

create table ARTIST_SONG_CONNECTION(
    SONG_C REF song_t not null,
    ARTIST_C REF artist_t not null
);
```

So what I want to do is to make a procedure, that inserts a new song of an artist knowing his id and make a reference to a particular song and a particular artist that are located on their tables.

Is it possible to do that with such a database structure, or do I need to make a table having objects like `CREATE TABLE SONGS_REF OF song_t`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use object then use object-derived tables:

```sql
CREATE TYPE artist_t AS OBJECT
(
    ARTISTID      INTEGER,
    NAME          varchar2(100),
    SURNAME       varchar2(100),
    DATE_OF_BIRTH date
);

CREATE TYPE song_t AS OBJECT
(
    SONGID           INTEGER,
    TITLE            varchar2(100),
    GENRE            varchar2(100),
    DATE_OF_CREATION date,
    BPM              NUMBER,
    artist           REF artist_t
);
```

Then you can create the tables:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE artist_seq;

CREATE SEQUENCE song_seq;

CREATE TABLE artist OF artist_t(
  artistid      DEFAULT artist_seq.NEXTVAL
                PRIMARY KEY,
  name          NOT NULL,
  surname       NOT NULL,
  date_of_birth NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE song OF song_t(
    SONGID           DEFAULT song_seq.NEXTVAL
                     PRIMARY KEY
                     NOT NULL,
    DATE_OF_CREATION DEFAULT sysdate
);

ALTER TABLE song ADD SCOPE FOR (artist) IS artist;
```

However, you cannot specify an `IDENTITY` column for object-derived tables (but you can use `DEFAULT` with a sequence).

---

#### Update

If you want `artist_song_connection` details then you can use a `VIEW` from the `song` table:

```sql
CREATE VIEW artist_song_connection (song, artist) AS
SELECT REF(s),
       s.artist
FROM   song s;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y4n8RDkW)

Comment: Hmm ok, that seems like a good answer but it is for my school project so I need to meet certain requirements. I need to know whether it is possible to "link" one row from SONG table into SONG_C REF song_t variable in ARTIST_SONG_CONNECTION table or do I need to make a table of objects.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like an *ordinary* referential integrity issue - just create a foreign key from `song` table to `artist`, including a new column (`artistid`) into the `song` table.

I don't think you need any additional type (while you created two of them).

---

```
SQL> create table artist(
  2      artistid integer generated always as identity primary key not null,
  3      name varchar2(100) not null,
  4      surname varchar2(100) not null,
  5      date_of_birth date
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> create table song(
  2      songid integer generated always as identity primary key not null,
  3      title varchar2(100),
  4      genre varchar2(100),
  5      date_of_creation date default sysdate,
  6      bpm number,
  7      --
  8      artistid integer constraint fk_song_art references artist (artistid)
  9  );

Table created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_insert_song
  2    (par_title    in song.title%type,
  3     par_genre    in song.genre%type,
  4     par_date     in song.date_of_creation%type,
  5     par_bpm      in song.bpm%type,
  6     par_artistid in song.artistid%type
  7    )
  8  is
  9  begin
 10    insert into song (title, genre, date_of_creation, bpm, artistid)
 11      values (par_title, par_genre, par_date, par_bpm, par_artistid);
 12  end;
 13  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Comment: This is obviously the best solution for this problem, but I really need to know whether my idea is ok, or do I need to create tables of object. It's for my university project so I need to satisfy object-oriented requirements.

Comment: Even if you needed additional table, it would be enough if it was just `create table song_artist (songid integer, artistid integer)` (you'd also add foreign key constraints to both tables and create composite unique (or primary) key on both columns). But, if you have to satisfy object-oriented requirements, go for it. Oracle is a **relational** database; the fact that it supports *object-oriented* stuff doesn't mean we should (ab)use it. I understand - that's for educational purposes so you can't do nor say much about it.

Comment: Thanks for help, however I really don't know how to "attach" a row from SONG into ARTIST_SONG_CONNECTION.SONG_C reference. I don't think that I should use a constructor, because it would create a separate object, and I need to give it a "pointer" of some kind.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't assist with that, I don't use object-oriented features. Hopefully, someone else will see this question and provide help. Good luck!